# R not found and no graph

Tags: r

I am new to R, and was given a script by a co-worker, I edited the script to work with my data set but have some errors that I cannot resolve.

**I'm getting:**

1. Error in summary(fitusers_log) : object 'fitusers_log' not found. This is happening for not only this one but for fitusers_log10 and fitusers_sqrt.

**The Script**

```
    users<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T, sep=",")
    date<-users[,1]
    OI<-users[,2]
    DO<-users[,3]
    UC<-users[,4]
    AT<-users[,5]
    ASA<-users[,6]

    fitusers<-lm(ASA ~ (0+OI+DO+UC+AT))

    fitusers_log<-lm(logASA ~ (0+logOI+logDO+logUC+logAT))
    summary(fitusers_log)

    fitusers_log10<-lm(log10ASA ~ (0+log10ASA:+log10OI+log10DO+log10UC+log10AT))
    summary(fitusers_log10)

    summary(fitusers_log)

    fitusers_sqrt<-lm(sqASA ~ (0+sqOI+sqDO+sqUC+sqAT))
    summary(fitusers_sqrt)

    fitusers<-lm(ASA ~ (0+OI+DO+UC+AT))
    summary(fitusers)

    opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0)) 
    plot(fitusers_log10, las = 1)  
    par(opar) 

    logASA<-log(ASA)
    logOI<-log(OI)
    logDO<-log(DO)
    logUC<-log(UC)
    logAT<-log(AT)

    log10ASA<-log(ASA,10)
    log10OI<-log(OI,10)
    log10DO<-log(DO,10)
    log10UC<-log(UC,10)
    log10AT<-log(AT,10)

    sqASA<-sqrt(ASA)
    sqOI<-sqrt(OI)
    sqDO<-sqrt(DO)
    sqUC<-sqrt(UC)
    sqAT<-sqrt(AT)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: At the bottom you define a bunch of variables like `logASA` that you used near the top. You need to define your variables before you use them. If you cut from `logASA <- log(ASA)` to the end and paste it before the `fitusers<-lm(ASA...` line, it might work.

Comment: Also, in your `fitusers_log10` definition, you have `log10ASA:+...`, which looks like a typo. You shouldn't have a colon and a plus next to each other.

Comment: oh Ill make those changes, thanks.

Comment: Still missing a graph, but I am getting some results now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Expanding comment into answer...

At the bottom you define a bunch of variables like `logASA` that you used near the top. You need to define your variables before you use them. If you cut from `logASA <- log(ASA)` to the end and paste it before the `fitusers<-lm(ASA...` line, it might work. Also you have a typo with a plus and a colon next to each other.

For plotting, you should probably re-arrange to this:

```
opar <- par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0)) 
par(opar) 
plot(fitusers_log10, las = 1)
```

Or, probably even better to save the original par values as `opar`

```
opar <- par()
par(mfrow = c(2,2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0)) 
plot(fitusers_log10, las = 1) 
par(opar)
```

If you still don't see a plot, run the line `plot(1, 1)`. If that doesn't display a (very boring) plot the problem is with your R set-up. You could ask your co-worker for help or ask a new question including your session details, OS, whether you're using RStudio, etc.

Comment: I was able to get them all to run once I pulled them out and ran them separately. And I didnt need the extra assignments on the bottom, just pulled in the file, assigned the columns, and just the few snips with the plotting.  `fitusersLog10<-lm(log10(ASA) ~ (0+log10(OI)+log10(UC)+log10(AHT)))
summary(fitusersLog10)`